# Copying and reorganizing data from one table to another in sqlite3 with python

Tags: python, sqlite

Here's my issue. I have a bunch of data organized like this:

(bad_table)

**Name**.......**Thing**...... **Count**

Dave........Houses.......1

Bob..........Cars............2

Jeff...........Boats..........1

Bob..........Houses.......1

Dave........Kids............3

Jeff..........Cars............3

And I’d like to have it organized like this:

(good_table)

**Name.....Houses.......Boats.....Cars**

Dave...........1................0.............0

Bob.............1................0.............2

Jeff..............0................1.............3

This is simplified; I’d actually like to make a table with hundreds of Things/Columns, but you get the idea. 
My approach has been to create a good_table with columns for Name, Houses, Boats, Cars, and rows for Dave, Bob and Jeff, but with no other values filled in.
Then for each Name, I would create a list of tuples (I think) from the original bad_table by saying, for example

```
Items = cur.execute(“SELECT Thing, Count FROM bad_table WHERE Name = Dave”)
```

Which gives me an “Items” that looks like [(‘Houses’, 1), (‘Boats’, 0), (‘Cars’, 0), (‘Kids’, 3)].
Then I would say,

```
For item in Items: 
    Thing = item[0]
    Count = item[1]
    cur.execute(“INSERT INTO good_table ? = ? WHERE Name = Dave”, (Thing, Count))
```

Which should, I would think, in the first instance translate to

```
“INSERT INTO good_table Houses = 1 WHERE Name = Dave”
```

This doesn’t produce any errors when I run it, but it also doesn’t actually insert anything into my good_table.
I’ve also tried running it with

```
(“UPDATE good_table SET ? = ? WHERE Name = Dave”, (Name, Count))
```

in case the problem was that sqlite3 was treating the ‘None’ values in the (to my mind) empty columns as already filled in. But, that didn’t work either.

If you can’t tell, I’m pretty new to all of this (python, SQL, etc.) and rely a lot on trial-and-error (along with, of course, a very thorough reading of the documentation).

The potential sources of my problem that I can think of are:

1) Not every “Thing” from the bad_table corresponds to a column in the good_table (e.g. “Kids”). I would hope that sqlite would simply skip over my attempts to “INSERT INTO” the good_table data that won’t fit there, but I don’t know that.

2) More likely, though, is that I’m formatting something wrong, or leaving out a comma or a set of curly braces or something where I need them. Which is why I’ve come to you good people for advice.

It doesn’t seem like what I’m trying to do should be very complicated, but I’m completely stumped and I’d really appreciate it if anyone can point out where I’ve gone wrong or suggest a better approach.

Comment: At your first run, there is **no** `"Dave"` in your table, therefore `WHERE Name = Dave` will fail.

Comment: You cannot bind column names (ie use `?` substituion), therefore neither the INSERT nor UPDATE will work.